# Is there a way for the pact consumer to hit the live provider service instead of Mock and generate the contract file?

Tags: java, pact

I'm trying to generate a pact contract file from my consumer API test by hitting the live provider service (dev) instead of using the provider mock.
However, I'm getting the below error. Anyone knows how to resolve this or is this actually feasible to hit the provider from consumer test? Thanks

```
au.com.dius.pact.consumer.PactMismatchesException: The following requests were not received:
    method: GET
    path: <API path>
    query: {}
    headers: <headers>
    matchers: MatchingRules(rules={})
    generators: Generators(categories={})
    body: MISSING

    at au.com.dius.pact.consumer.junit.JUnitTestSupport.validateMockServerResult(JUnitTestSupport.kt:60)
    at au.com.dius.pact.consumer.junit5.PactConsumerTestExt.afterTestExecution(PactConsumerTestExt.kt:367)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAfterTestExecutionCallbacks$9(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:233)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAllAfterMethodsOrCallbacks$13(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:273)
    .....
org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

No, Pact is not designed this way. Even if it were, it would miss out on a key benefit of contract testing: full visibility into the actual used surface area of the API.

If you were to only employ record/replay style tests here, we would not know what the consumer actually uses in the **response** from a given Provider.

This would now mean the Provider must assume that for a given endpoint, all of the fields are important to a Consumer.

Now if a Provider wants to modify or delete a field, it must assume every consumer relies on it and now must version their API.

But if the Provider knew that their consumers only needed a subset of the fields, it would be safe to remove/change the ones that weren't currently in use, without needing to version the API or indeed communicate that change outside of their team.

Furthermore, Pact is very much intended to be a unit testing tool. Hitting real endpoints adds a lot more indeterminism into the equation and makes it harder to be very specific and targeted with your testing.